# How to insert my program to MFC dialog?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am a new comer in MFC programming. I have already wrote a program, and I want to display the program in a graphical interface. So I use MFC dialog to realize it, but it does not work when runs.

Once the `OK` button is clicked :

```
void CTest1Dlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
  UpdateData();
  FILE *stream; 
  freopen_s( &stream, "out_file.ps", "w", stdout ); // reopen stream as .ps
  if (mode == 1)                                    //main() in my code 
  {
    ActiveAuthoring();
  }
  else if (mode == 0)
  {
    XYAuthoring();
  }
  else 
  {
    ActiveAuthoring();
  }
  cout<<"showpage"<<endl;
  UpdateData(FALSE);
  OnOK();
}
```

My code is in `converter.cpp`, so first I change `converter.cpp` to `converter.h` and include it in `Test1Dlg.cpp`. And then when the `OK` button click run the `main()` in my code.

However, I discover that it seems the parameter does not transfer from the graphical interface to my code, although I relevant the edit control box to every parameter. So the dialog does not work. Could some one help me?

**EDIT**

[image: this]

The eight edit control boxes are the parameters I used in my `coverter.cpp`.

My code is aim to use eight parameters to generate some strings, these strings are saved in a file named as `out_file` which format is `.ps`.

Comment: What is "`stdout`"? Do you mean to write to console? I think MFC cannot directly write to console. Something like `AttachConsole` has to be called.

Comment: @doctorlove I have updated my problem. There are eight parameters in my code as showed in pic.

Comment: @rajraj Not exactly. My code generate some strings based on eight parameters, and save them in out_file.ps.

Comment: Show us more code and tell us what exactly does not work. And where is cout supposed to go ?

Comment: Not understanding what you want ??

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways you get data from dialog controls to "your code"... if you're using the Visual Studio dialog editor and adding the controls there, it will generate code inside of `virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)` for you to move data to and from your controls when the dialog gets initialized and terminates.  You'll have a line like `DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_DIGITS, m_Digits);` that the IDE adds that does the exchange.  You can also just set and get the data directly if you wanted, e.g. `GetDlgItem( IDC_DIGITS )->GetWindowText( m_Digits );`